# Synchronization of Multithreading in C

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, synchronization, mutex

I am new to MultiThreading in C. I am trying to write a code where we use multithreading. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <limits.h>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int finish = 0; 
int mess_size=15;

double exponGenerator(double myLamda)
{
    double pv = 0.0;
    while (1)
    {
        pv = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
        if (pv != 1)
            break;
    }
    pv = (-1.0 / myLamda) * log(1 - pv);
    return pv;
}

struct packet{
    int val;
    time_t start_time;
    double service_time;
};
struct queue{
    struct packet arr_pac[10000];
    int start;
    int end;
    int size;
};

double lambda = 5;
double servicerate = 5;
struct queue q1 ;
struct queue q2; 

struct queue initialiseQueue(){
   struct queue q ;
   q.start = 0;
   q.end = 0;
   q.size=0;
   return q;
}

struct process1{
int method;
double lambda;
struct queue Q1;
struct queue Q2;
};

struct process2{
struct queue q;
double u;
};

struct process1 queueenv(int method)
{
    struct process1 temp ;
    temp.method = method;
    temp.lambda = lambda;
    temp.Q1 = q1;
    temp.Q2 = q2;
return temp;
}

struct process2 serverenv(double u, struct queue q)
{
    struct process2 temp;
    temp.u = u;
    temp.q = q;
return temp;
}

int enque(struct queue q){
if (q.size < 10) 
{ 
  
  struct packet temp ;
  temp.start_time = time(NULL);

  temp.val = 1;
  q.arr_pac[q.end] = temp;

  q.end = q.end +1;

  q.size = q.end - q.start;
//printf("  %d",q.arr_pac[0].end);
  return q.size  ;
}
else{
return -1;
}
}

struct packet deque(struct queue q) {
struct packet temp ;
printf("  %d ",q.end);
if(q.size >0){
  printf("entered");
  temp=q.arr_pac[q.start];
  temp.service_time = difftime(time(NULL),temp.start_time);
  q.start=q.start +1;
  q.size = q.end - q.start;
  return temp;
}
else{
printf("entered 2");
temp.service_time=0 ;
return temp;
}
}

int randomSelection(){
if(rand()%2 ==0){
return enque(q1);
}
else{
return enque(q2);
}
}

int minQueue(){
 if(q1.size > q2.size){
 return enque(q2);
}
else{
return enque(q1);
}
}

void queueprocess(struct process1 params){
    double blockCounter = 0.0;
    double blockPro = 0.0;
    int queLenCounter = 0;
    int averageQueueLen = 0;
    int i = 0;
 
  if (params.method == 0) 
    {
printf(" this is the %d =0",params.method);
        for (i = 0; i < mess_size ; i++)
        {
            
            double interval = exponGenerator(params.lambda);
            sleep(interval);
            int res = randomSelection();
            
            if (res == -1) 
            { 
                blockCounter++;
                queLenCounter = queLenCounter +10;
            }
        else{

           queLenCounter = queLenCounter + res;
                   //printf(" %d ",queLenCounter);
        }
        }
    }
    else if (params.method == 1)
    { 
printf(" this is the %d =1  ",params.method);
        for (i = 0; i < mess_size ; i++)
        {
            double interval = exponGenerator(params.lambda);
            sleep(interval);
            int res = minQueue();
            printf("  %d mn",q1.end);
            if (res == -1) 
            {
                blockCounter++;
                queLenCounter = queLenCounter +10;
            }
        else{
           queLenCounter = queLenCounter +res;
        }
        }
    }
    blockPro = blockCounter/mess_size;
    averageQueueLen = queLenCounter/mess_size;
    printf("Blocking Probability is : %f",&blockPro);
    printf("Average Que Length is : %d",averageQueueLen);
    finish = 1;
    return;

}
void serverprocess(struct process2 serverparams) 
{
 struct packet processed_arr[10000];
 int i=0,j;
    while(1)
    { 
        if (finish == 1 && serverparams.q.size == 0) 
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            double interval = exponGenerator(serverparams.u);
 
            sleep(interval);
            
            struct packet k = deque(serverparams.q);
             
        if(!k.service_time){
 
            processed_arr[i]=k;

            i++;
        }
        }
    }
float sourjanCounter=0;
float sourjan;
for(j=0;j<i;j++){
printf(" %f",processed_arr[j].service_time);
sourjanCounter = sourjanCounter+ processed_arr[j].service_time;
}
sourjan = sourjanCounter/(i-1);
printf("Average Sourjan Time is : %f ", &sourjan);
}

DWORD WINAPI threadone(){
    printf(" thread one ");
    struct process1 queueparams = queueenv(1);
   
    queueprocess(queueparams);
}

DWORD WINAPI threadtwo(){  
    struct process2 server1params = serverenv(servicerate, q1);
    serverprocess(server1params);
}

DWORD WINAPI threadthree(){
    struct process2 server2params = serverenv(servicerate, q2);
    serverprocess(server2params);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    HANDLE hThrds[3];
    int i = 0;

    /*if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Incorrect parameters!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    double lambda = atof(argv[1]);
    double servicerate = atof(argv[2]);*/

    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        DWORD thread1,thread2,thread3;
        hThrds[2]=CreateThread(NULL,0,  threadone, NULL,0,&thread1);
        hThrds[0]=CreateThread(NULL,0, threadtwo, NULL,0,&thread2);
        hThrds[1]=CreateThread(NULL,0, threadthree, NULL,0,&thread3); 
        WaitForMultipleObjects(3, hThrds,TRUE, INFINITE);
    }
}
```

In my code I have a function called `enque`, which is called from a function called `queueprocess`. `q1` is a structure and is defined globally, It is accessed by multiple functions at the same time. I am trying to change the value of `q1` inside function `enque` and when I print its value inside the function `enque` it's value is correct, but if I try to print its value inside function `queueprocess` its value is 0. As a result of this my code is not moving forward. I have read about `mutex`, but I don't know what is mutex equivalent to win32. I don't know why mutex should be used for my program as well, since I am just accessing `q1` from another function but I am not trying to change its value.

Can anyone please explain me why I am facing the problem mentioned above and what would be the possible solution of it?

Comment: "*I am just accesing q1 from another function but I am not trying to change its value*". Doesn't matter. If you are changing in *any* thread then all threads need to synchronise. Otherwise a reading thread may read the struct when the writing thread has updated some but not all of the struct fields it needs to.

Comment: @kaylum in this case it is enough to make it atomic. Synchronisation means much more than only this.

Comment: @0___________ Yeah you're right. My terminology was a bit too loose.

Comment: @Ram You need to learn some IPC basics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-synchronization - this link is for Microsoft implementation. But basically all the systems use very similar mechanisms.

Comment: Yes and no, @0___________.  It is true that synchronization is not required to access atomic objects from multiple threads, but accessing *a member* of an atomic structure has undefined behavior (C17 6.5.2.3/5).  As footnote 99 clarifies, to get at a member of an atomic structure, one must make a non-atomic copy via structure assignment, and access the member of the copy.  That's a bit more than just making the structure atomic.

Comment: Edit your post and format your code. It's an unreadable mess.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I did not say: declare them as atomic. Only make the operation atomic. Synchronization mechanisms do much more than only that - they also manage the tasks behaviour. And that was my point.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft documentation:

> You can use a mutex object to protect a shared resource from
> simultaneous access by multiple threads or processes. Each thread must
> wait for ownership of the mutex before it can execute the code that
> accesses the shared resource. For example, if several threads share
> access to a database, the threads can use a mutex object to permit
> only one thread at a time to write to the database.
>
> The following example uses the CreateMutex function to create a mutex
> object and the CreateThread function to create worker threads.
>
> When a thread of this process writes to the database, it first
> requests ownership of the mutex using the WaitForSingleObject
> function. If the thread obtains ownership of the mutex, it writes to
> the database and then releases its ownership of the mutex using the
> ReleaseMutex function.
>
> This example uses structured exception handling to ensure that the
> thread properly releases the mutex object. The __finally block of code
> is executed no matter how the __try block terminates (unless the __try
> block includes a call to the TerminateThread function). This prevents
> the mutex object from being abandoned inadvertently.
>
> If a mutex is abandoned, the thread that owned the mutex did not
> properly release it before terminating. In this case, the status of
> the shared resource is indeterminate, and continuing to use the mutex
> can obscure a potentially serious error. Some applications might
> attempt to restore the resource to a consistent state; this example
> simply returns an error and stops using the mutex. For more
> information, see Mutex Objects.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define THREADCOUNT 2

HANDLE ghMutex; 

DWORD WINAPI WriteToDatabase( LPVOID );

int main( void )
{
    HANDLE aThread[THREADCOUNT];
    DWORD ThreadID;
    int i;

    // Create a mutex with no initial owner

    ghMutex = CreateMutex( 
        NULL,              // default security attributes
        FALSE,             // initially not owned
        NULL);             // unnamed mutex

    if (ghMutex == NULL) 
    {
        printf("CreateMutex error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Create worker threads

    for( i=0; i < THREADCOUNT; i++ )
    {
        aThread[i] = CreateThread( 
                     NULL,       // default security attributes
                     0,          // default stack size
                     (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) WriteToDatabase, 
                     NULL,       // no thread function arguments
                     0,          // default creation flags
                     &ThreadID); // receive thread identifier

        if( aThread[i] == NULL )
        {
            printf("CreateThread error: %d\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Wait for all threads to terminate

    WaitForMultipleObjects(THREADCOUNT, aThread, TRUE, INFINITE);

    // Close thread and mutex handles

    for( i=0; i < THREADCOUNT; i++ )
        CloseHandle(aThread[i]);

    CloseHandle(ghMutex);

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI WriteToDatabase( LPVOID lpParam )
{ 
    // lpParam not used in this example
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpParam);

    DWORD dwCount=0, dwWaitResult; 

    // Request ownership of mutex.

    while( dwCount < 20 )
    { 
        dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject( 
            ghMutex,    // handle to mutex
            INFINITE);  // no time-out interval
 
        switch (dwWaitResult) 
        {
            // The thread got ownership of the mutex
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0: 
                __try { 
                    // TODO: Write to the database
                    printf("Thread %d writing to database...\n", 
                            GetCurrentThreadId());
                    dwCount++;
                } 

                __finally { 
                    // Release ownership of the mutex object
                    if (! ReleaseMutex(ghMutex)) 
                    { 
                        // Handle error.
                    } 
                } 
                break; 

            // The thread got ownership of an abandoned mutex
            // The database is in an indeterminate state
            case WAIT_ABANDONED: 
                return FALSE; 
        }
    }
    return TRUE; 
}
```